# How to count cells that reply to a condition

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Lets say I have this kind of spreadsheet:

---

1. P1A | P2A | P3A| RA
2. 1 | 2 | 3 | 1
3. 2 | 4 | 2 | 4
4. 1 | 3 | 3 | 3

---

Where each row represents answers to a question.
First row is title row. P1A - P3A is player1 through player3 answers and RA is the right answer.

Is it possible to add subtotal row which will show number of right answers for each player without adding extra columns for making "IF" tests.

So the total will look like this:
1 | 2 | 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sum product to find this. Use the formula like below

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4=$D2:$D4)*1)
```